# Python. Comparing two text document's contents

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare two text documents with python just to state whether the contents of the text documents are identical or not by returning a True/False answer.

```
filehandle1=open(filename1,"r")
filehandle2=open(filename2,"r")
for line1 in filehandle1:
    for line2 in filehandle2:
        if line1==line2:
            print (True)
        else:
            print (False)
```

I'm quite new to Python and don't have much knowledge about it. I was wondering if anyone knows a simple way of just comparing two text documents.

The documents i'm using contain:

Text1:

```
123456789

12345678
1234567

123456
12345

1234
123

12
```

Text2:

```
12

123
1234

12345
123456

1234567
12345678

123456789
```

Text3:

```
123456789

12345678
1234567

123456
12345

1234
123

12
```

I'd appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Compare? Is there any output that you expected?

Comment: Why not just compare the [`hash`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash) of the file contents?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this so i'm not familiar with the hash.

Comment: The output would be a Boolean. I'm just in a jam.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney I don't think there's a speed/memory advantageous in this case.

Comment: What I basically want to do is type in the paths for two text documents into a definition like 'code' def EqualContent(filename1,filename2) and get a Boolean back stating whether the content of the text documents are identical or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to compare if the two files contain the same text, you can just compare them as a whole, instead of a line by line basis:

```
filehandle1.read() == filehandle2.read()
```

Also dont forget to close your files after opening them.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [Filecmp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html) module:

```
 filecmp.cmp(f1, f2[, shallow])

  returns True is two file are identical else false
```

Answer (score 1):

@Hackaholic's answer (using `filecmp`) is probably best.  However, if you do want to do the comparison yourself, by line, then the best approach may be:

```
def EqualContent(filename1, filename2):
    with open(filename1) as f1, open(filename2) as f2:
        return all(s1==s2 for s1, s2 in zip(f1, f2))
```

(in Python 2, `import future_builtins` to make sure built-ins work like in Python 3!).

This does not require enough memory to keep both files in memory at once (like approaches based on `read` or `readlines` do), just one line from each, at a time; and, if the files do differ, it minimizes the required amount of I/O; that's because `all` is designed to "fail fast" -- `return False` as soon as it finds two lines that differ (it does need to go to the end before it can `return True`, of course).

In Python 2, without the `import future_builtins`, `zip` would in fact read all lines from both files and thus nullify the advantages (Python 3 is smarter -- and you can make Python 2.7 just as smart with that `import`!-).

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("filename1.txt") as f:
    with open ("filename2.txt") as d:
        for x,y in zip (f,d):
            if x==y:
                print (True)
            else:
                print (False)
```

Here is a better method. `zip` for identical match-short way.